# how can I solve TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable in python

Tags: python

```
import pyfiglet
pyfiglet.print_figlet("Niko CyMax",'puffy')

num_list=[ (1,2) , (3,1000) , (5,6) , (9,10) , (8,500) , (70,400) ]

num_list_manual_sort=num_list.sort()
num_list_pro_sort=num_list.sort(key = lambda x: x[1])

for i in num_list_manual_sort:
    print(i)

for i in num_list_pro_sort:
    print(i)
```

and error is:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Your variables (num_list_manual_sort and num_list_pro_sort) are getting assigned None.  .sort() function doesn't work on list of object (In your case a tuple).

Comment: You could use the `sorted` function rather than the `sort` method.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept an answer (If there is one that fixed your problem) by clicking the grey checkmark on the left of it. This gets you +2 reputation and the answer  author +15

Answer (score 0):

Sorting a list with `sort()` changes the list *in place*, that means, the list `num_list` is changed directly, instead of the sorted list being returned and the original one left intact. You want to use  the builtin `sorted` function, which does exactly what you want:

```py
import pyfiglet
pyfiglet.print_figlet("Niko CyMax",'puffy')

num_list=[(1, 2), (3, 1000), (5, 6), (9, 10), (8, 500), (70, 400)]

num_list_manual_sort = sorted(num_list)
num_list_pro_sort = sorted(num_list, key=lambda x: x[1])

for i in num_list_manual_sort:
    print(i)

for i in num_list_pro_sort:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score -2):

When you are sorting a list with `sort` method, you are changing the list itself, and `None` is returned.

```
num_list_manual_sort=num_list.sort()
num_list_pro_sort=num_list.sort(key = lambda x: x[1])
```

Both `num_list_manual_sort` and `num_list_pro_sort` will hold `None`.
In case you want to get the list back, you can replace it by:

```
num_list.sort()
num_list_manual_sort = num_list[:]
num_list.sort(key = lambda x: x[1])
num_list_pro_sort = num_list[:]
```

There are more options for doing that, depends on your need.

Comment: What is wrong with my answer? It explained the problem and suggets a way for handling it.

Comment: It should be clarified that `num_list[:]` creates a copy of `num_list` so it won't get modified by future changes. It should also be clarified that this method changes `num_list`, so if you need `num_list` to remain in its initial order, this isn't the method for you.

Comment: I thought it would be clear for the reader, but i understand your claims. Thank you for elaborating.